# Why does JsonConvert deserialize object fail with int but not long

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core, json.net

When testing av web API created in .Net 6.0, we found that when a user of the API sent decimal number on a int you got a 400 error stating that it fail to parse the json because of the decimal on the int value. But doing the same on a long value worked fine it just removed the decimal numbers.

So to test if this (guessing that MS uses Newonsoft.Json), I made a little cmd test app to test the scenario. And the same thing happens there long pareses loosing it decimals, and int fails.

So is this a bug in the parser or by design?
[Edit] Should it not also fail on long?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomData>(@"{""aInt"":1, ""ALong"":2.2}"); 

Console.WriteLine(data.ALong); // output 2

var data2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomData>(@"{""aInt"":1.2, ""ALong"":2}"); // exception

Console.WriteLine(data2.AInt);


internal class SomData
{
   public int AInt { get; set; }
   public long ALong { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The inconsistency seems like a bug, Json.NET should behave the same for `short`, `int`, `long`, `ushort`, `uint` and `ulong`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is by design. we can see this discussion [Error converting float value to integer in Web API #654](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/654). The author's answer was below.

> Later versions of Json.NET throw an error when deserializing a floating-point value onto an integer property.

I would always use `decimal` when you are using floating-point numbers.

```
internal class SomData
{
    public decimal AInt { get; set; }
    public decimal ALong { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

I had seen the source code of Json.Net

The Int value will will go into `else` part as below code from JsonTextReader in [ReadType.ReadAsInt32](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/f7e7bd05d9280f17993500085202ff4ea150564a/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs#L2052-L2064)

which might as author say by design.

```
ParseResult parseResult = ConvertUtils.Int32TryParse(_stringReference.Chars, _stringReference.StartIndex, _stringReference.Length, out int value);
if (parseResult == ParseResult.Success)
{
    numberValue = value;
}
else if (parseResult == ParseResult.Overflow)
{
    throw ThrowReaderError("JSON integer {0} is too large or small for an Int32.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _stringReference.ToString()));
}
else
{
    throw ThrowReaderError("Input string '{0}' is not a valid integer.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _stringReference.ToString()));
}
```

but let's see [ReadType.ReadAsInt64](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/f7e7bd05d9280f17993500085202ff4ea150564a/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs#L2198-L2225) that `else` part is a lot of different between `ReadAsInt32`.

At First, it would get to `else` let value(`object` type) to store as float value as below code.

```
ParseResult parseResult = ConvertUtils.Int64TryParse(_stringReference.Chars, _stringReference.StartIndex, _stringReference.Length, out long value);
if (parseResult == ParseResult.Success)
{
    numberValue = value;
    numberType = JsonToken.Integer;
}
else if (parseResult == ParseResult.Overflow)
{
#if HAVE_BIG_INTEGER
    string number = _stringReference.ToString();

    if (number.Length > MaximumJavascriptIntegerCharacterLength)
    {
        throw ThrowReaderError("JSON integer {0} is too large to parse.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _stringReference.ToString()));
    }

    numberValue = BigIntegerParse(number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    numberType = JsonToken.Integer;
#else
    throw ThrowReaderError("JSON integer {0} is too large or small for an Int64.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _stringReference.ToString()));
#endif
}
else
{
    if (_floatParseHandling == FloatParseHandling.Decimal)
    {
        parseResult = ConvertUtils.DecimalTryParse(_stringReference.Chars, _stringReference.StartIndex, _stringReference.Length, out decimal d);
        if (parseResult == ParseResult.Success)
        {
            numberValue = d;
        }
        else
        {
            throw ThrowReaderError("Input string '{0}' is not a valid decimal.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _stringReference.ToString()));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string number = _stringReference.ToString();

        if (double.TryParse(number, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double d))
        {
            numberValue = d;
        }
        else
        {
            throw ThrowReaderError("Input string '{0}' is not a valid number.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _stringReference.ToString()));
        }
    }

    numberType = JsonToken.Float;
}
```

Then the number will be convert to Int64 by [JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/2b0f7a2492bbedbf5e381d0468f503a99e834dbc/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L998)

```
// this won't work when converting to a custom IConvertible
return Convert.ChangeType(value, contract.NonNullableUnderlyingType, culture);
```

so we can get `long` will not get execption but `int` will, not sure why `ReadAsInt64` allow store as float but `int` was not.

Comment: Should it not also fail on long?

Comment: @Gaotter Yes I guess it might be a bug, I am looking at its source code.

Comment: Probably wrong of me to ask here. I made an issue in git,
https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2664

Comment: @Gaotter I had seen source code between `int` & `long` but not sure they are different, I had edit my answer